# Disabling access to page if not logged in and then giving access once logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've seen similar questions here but none of them help my problem.
I am disabling access to pages unless the user logged in by using the following code

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: Login.php");
}
```

When that sends me to the log in page, I log in and it takes me to the main menu.
Then if I go to another page, it sends me back to log in again.
It's treating every page the same even after I log in when redirected.
What could be the problem?

After successful login I have this on the main menu

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
```

Comment: Do you set the session when you log in? Are you sure you never removed it in another line of code? Are your server session settings good?

Comment: You should use var_dump($_SESSION) and try to find if you ever set your session correctly, just add it in above the if statement and it will display on the screen.

Comment: While setting the session you are using 'user' and while retrieving you are using 'username' which is never set i think. So you are being redirected back again n again.

Comment: While setting the session you are using 'user' and while retrieving you are using 'username' which is never set i think. So you are being redirected back again n again.

Answer (score -1):

you set the session as 'user'

```
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['username'];
```

and checking the session with 'username'

do this

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("Location: Login.php");
```

}